# How do I populate the diagonals of a matrix with strings in python?

Tags: python, list, matrix

I'm trying to populate the diagonals of an empty matrix (list of lists) in python with the following code:

```
source=['a','b','c']

rows=[]
for x in source:
    rows.append('')
matrix=[]
for x in source:
    matrix.append(rows)

print "before populating", matrix

for x in range (0, len(source)):
    matrix[x][x]=source[x]

print "after populating", matrix
```

I realized that this is not the most efficient way to accomplish this, but this actually appears to be the least of my problems.

The output I got was this:

```
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c']]
```

But the output I was hoping for was this:

```
[['a', '', ''], ['', 'b', ''], ['', '', 'c']]
```

Any idea what went wrong? Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for x in source:
    matrix.append(rows)
```

You populate **matrix** with references to **rows**. You may use slices of **rows** to make a copy

```
>> rows = ['a','b','c']
>>> matrix = [rows[:] for _ in range(len(rows))]
>>> matrix
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c']]
>>> matrix[1][1]=' '
>>> matrix
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', ' ', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c']]
```

Comment: So that's the issue! Thanks! I was so confused!

Comment: I know - this may be confusing in Python. Unlike C++, assigning object in Python creates a reference to existing object - not a bitcopy. For simple lists, slice is the approach; for more complicated cases, use module **copy**

Answer (score 2):

A simple list comprehension should do it:

```
In [62]: source=['a','b','c']

In [63]: [[""]*i + [x] + [""]*(len(source)-i-1) for i,x in enumerate(source)]
Out[63]: [['a', '', ''], ['', 'b', ''], ['', '', 'c']]

In [64]: source=['a','b','c','d']

In [65]: [[""]*i + [x] + [""]*(len(source)-i-1) for i,x in enumerate(source)]
Out[65]: [['a', '', '', ''], ['', 'b', '', ''], ['', '', 'c', ''], ['', '', '', 'd']]
```

Comment: ISWYDT. Thanks! Doesn't tell me what was wrong with mine, but very economical and clear. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

the problem is withing this code:

```
rows=[]
for x in source:
    rows.append('')
matrix=[]
for x in source:
    matrix.append(rows)
```

you are giving the same **reference** each time.

```
for x in range (0, len(source)):
    matrix[x][x]=source[x]
```

this is going to modify the same object. solution: use a copy:

```
matrix=[]
for x in source:
    # use a copy.
    matrix.append(rows[:])
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a new row of independen elements for each row in your matrix. Doing `matrix.append(rows)` only inserts a references to the same list instance again and again.

Try `matrix.append(list(rows))` instead.

For more complicated cases the `copy` module may be helpful.

The root cause for your trouble stems from the fact that Python only handles references to object instance, it does not have a concept of "variable" like in C, so there is no copying of object when you make an assignment. Instead there is just a new reference.

Answer (score 1):

```
source=['a','b','c']

matrix = [['' if i!=j else source[i] for i in range(len(source))]
     for j in range(len(source))]
```

Answer (score 1):

Others have already explained what's happening with your code, but here's another option...

If you don't mind using `numpy` then:

```
import numpy as np
np.diag(['a', 'b', 'c']).tolist()
# [['a', '', ''], ['', 'b', ''], ['', '', 'c']]
```

And if you're going to be dealing with matrices then it's probably not a bad idea to look at `numpy` or `scipy` anyway...